Is there ways to find the most efficient geometrical structure for sunlight concentration?
we are researching for the most efficient geometrical structure of a concentrator. What we mean by 'most efficient' is that we are trying to get the most sunlight while sun is up. We are not trying to consider other variables such as wind or temperature. (We have searched about temperature and aerodynamical variables in the real world system. However, it was too complex for us to consider.)
We aim to make a concentrator without a solar tracking system. When we searched on the internet, current concentrators are these.

parabolic concentrator, compound parabolic concentrator
hyperbolic concentrator
dielectric totally internally reflecting concentrator
fresnel lens concentrator

Most of previous concentrators required a solar tracking system. For example, parabolic concentrators collect solar rays parellel to the axis. Therefore, it uses a solar tracking system to make the rays parellel to the axis.
Nevertheless, we want to find a structure where we don't need any trackers. Is there an approach to find an optimized structure? We have considered researching more about DTIRC, but we still don't quite have a feeling of how to research about this topic.
